# TypeError: a float is required...i converted all the values into float but still the error exists

Tags: machine-learning, svm

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X_log_train.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
X_log_train.fillna(9999, inplace=True)

SVM_model = SVC(
C=1.0,
kernel='rbf',
degree=3,
SVM_model.fit(X_log_train,y_train)
```

I am working on machine learning using data set of size 1.3 GB.

I converted all the values into `float` type and replace all the null values using dropna but still it gave the error

> Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

then I used this statement

```
X_log_train.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
X_log_train.fillna(9999, inplace=True)
```

Now it is giving me the error that a float is required. I don't get what my mistake is. Can anyone help understanding it?

Comment: Please tag your question with `python` and some variant of the `scikit` tag.

Comment: `X_log_train.fillna(9999, inplace=True)` here you are filling the nan values with an integer right? . I think the column with nan values expect a float value hence it is throwing error. Also while filling nan values keep `inplace = true`

Comment: what should i do now ..before this i converted all the values into float